# How to dynamically import an unsafe Python module with a timeout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, python-importlib

I need to dynamically load several potentially unsafe modules for testing purpose.

Regarding security, my script is executed by a low-access user.

Although, I still need a way to elegantly make the import process timeout as I have no guarantee that the module script will terminate. By example, it could contain a call to `input` or an infinite loop.

I am currently using `Thread.join` with a `timeout`, but this does not fully solve the issue since the script is then still alive in the background and there is no way to kill a thread.

```
from threading import Thread
import importlib.util

class ReturnThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().join(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._return

def loader(name, path):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module) # This may run into an infinite loop
    return module

module_loader = ReturnThread(loader, ('module_name', 'module/path'))
module_loader.start()
module = module_loader.join(timeout=0.1)

# The thread might still be alive here
if module is None:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

How can I import a module, but return `None` if the script timeouts?

Comment: importing module modifies global interpreter state, there is no safe way to interrupt it, python doesn’t allow that. besides python doesn’t expose a thread killing method.

Comment: but you could achieve the goal by doing stuff in child process, i could write an answer if you accept this .

Comment: @georgexsh There are of course some assumptions to be done. I am aware that if the module's author is aware this is what I am doing this with their script, they can pretty much break any attempt. Although this is aimed at building a correction script for grading Python coding assignments, so we can assume that there should be nothing too nasty in the modules. Since my script is rarely ran against more than a hundred assignments, threading kind of works, but it is not elegant.

Comment: That being said, what must be caught and interrupted would be mainly infinite loops and undesired input calls.

Comment: there is no way to break an infinite a loop in python if it is not cooperative IMO. even though python has `pthread_kill` api exposed, but as only the main thread could execute the signal handler, the signal has no effect on the thread in the dead loop. executing code in a child process is more feasible here.

Comment: Can a subprocess be made to return the module as simply as the thread did? My intuition tells me returning a Python object from the process can be a mess. And I'll have a look at `pthread_kill`, this may work in this very particular case.

Comment: no, pass a module object between process is not easy, because you cant pickle it. instead, move most of the grading logic to the child process, send back the result to parent. the advantage is, you could clean up a rogue process reliably, always start from a fresh state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reliably kill importing a module. You are essentially executing live code in your own interpreter, so all bets are off.

### Never import untrusted code

First of all, there is no way to safely import unsafe modules from an untrusted source. It doesn't matter if you are using a low-access user. **NEVER IMPORT UNTRUSTED CODE**. The moment the code is imported it could have exploited security holes in your system well beyond the Python process itself. Python is a general purpose programming language, not a sandboxed environment, and any code you import has the full run of your system

Instead of using a low-access user, **at the very least** run this is a virtual machine. The virtual machine environment can be set up from a known-good snapshot, without network access, and be shut down when a time limit has been reached. You can then compare the snapshots to see what, if anything, the code has attempted to do. Any security breach at that level is short-lived and without value. Also see [*Best practices for execution of untrusted code*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code) over on Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

### You can't stop the code from undoing your work

Next, because you can't control what the imported code does, it can trivially interfere with any attempts to time out the code. The first thing the imported code could do is revoke the protections you put in place! Imported code can access all of Python's global state, including the code that triggered the import. The code could set the [thread switch interval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setswitchinterval) to the maximum value (internally, an unsigned long modelling milliseconds, so the max is `((2 ** 32) - 1)` milliseconds, just a smidgen under 71 minutes 35 seconds) to mess with scheduling.

### You can't stop threads, reliably, if they don't want to be stopped

Exiting a thread in Python is [handled by raising a exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#_thread.exit):

> Raise the `SystemExit` exception. **When not caught**, this will cause the thread to exit silently.

(Bold emphasis mine.)

From pure Python code, you can only exit a thread from code *running in that thread*, but there is a way around this, see below.

But you can't guarantee that the code you are importing isn't just catching and handling all exceptions; if that's the case, the code will just keep on running. At that point it becomes a weapons race; can your thread manage to insert the exception at the point the other thread is inside an exception handler? Then you can exit that thread, otherwise, you lose. You'd have to keep trying until you succeed.

### A thread that waits on blocking I/O or started a blocking operation in a native extension can't (easily) be killed

If the code you import waits on blocking I/O (such as an `input()` call) then you can't interrupt that call. Raising an exception does nothing, and you can't use signals (as Python handles those on the main thread *only*). You'd have to find and close every open I/O channel they could be blocked on. This is outside of the scope of my answer here, there are just too many ways to start I/O operations.

If the code started something implemented in native code (a Python extension) and *that* blocks, all bets are off entirely.

### Your interpreter state can be hosed by the time you stop them

The code you import could have done anything by the time you managed to stop them. Imported modules could have been replaced. Source code on disk can have been altered. You can't be certain that no other threads have been started. Anything is possible in Python, so assume that it has happened.

### If you wanted to do this, anyway

With those caveats in mind, so you accept that

- The code you import can do malicious things to the OS they are running in, without you being able to stop them from within the same process or even OS
- The code you import could stop your code from working.
- The code you import might have imported and started things you didn't want importing or started.
- The code might start operations that prevent you from stopping the thread altogether

then you can time out imports by running them in a separate thread, and then raise a `SystemExit` exception in the thread. You can raise exceptions in another thread by calling the [`PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc` C-API function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc) via the [`ctypes.pythonapi` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls). The Python test suite [actually uses this path in a test](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/260ec2c36abd73bac51489108409160427979ede/Lib/test/test_threading.py#L179-L267), I used that as a template for my solution below.

So here is a full implementation that does just that, and raises an custom `UninterruptableImport` exception (a subclass of `ImportError`) if the import could not be interrupted. If the import raised an exception, then that exception is re-raised in the thread that started the import process:

```
"""Import a module within a timeframe

Uses the PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc C API and a signal handler to interrupt
the stack of calls triggered from an import within a timeframe

No guarantees are made as to the state of the interpreter after interrupting

"""

import ctypes
import importlib
import random
import sys
import threading
import time

_set_async_exc = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc
_set_async_exc.argtypes = (ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.py_object)
_system_exit = ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)


class UninterruptableImport(ImportError):
    pass


class TimeLimitedImporter():
    def __init__(self, modulename, timeout=5):
        self.modulename = modulename
        self.module = None
        self.exception = None
        self.timeout = timeout

        self._started = None
        self._started_event = threading.Event()
        self._importer = threading.Thread(target=self._import, daemon=True)
        self._importer.start()
        self._started_event.wait()

    def _import(self):
        self._started = time.time()
        self._started_event.set()
        timer = threading.Timer(self.timeout, self.exit)
        timer.start()
        try:
            self.module = importlib.import_module(self.modulename)
        except Exception as e:
            self.exception = e
        finally:
            timer.cancel()

    def result(self, timeout=None):
        # give the importer a chance to finish first
        if timeout is not None:
            timeout += max(time.time() + self.timeout - self._started, 0)
        self._importer.join(timeout)
        if self._importer.is_alive():
            raise UninterruptableImport(
                f"Could not interrupt the import of {self.modulename}")
        if self.module is not None:
            return self.module
        if self.exception is not None:
            raise self.exception

    def exit(self):
        target_id = self._importer.ident
        if target_id is None:
            return
        # set a very low switch interval to be able to interrupt an exception
        # handler if SystemExit is being caught
        old_interval = sys.getswitchinterval()
        sys.setswitchinterval(1e-6)

        try:
            # repeatedly raise SystemExit until the import thread has exited.
            # If the exception is being caught by a an exception handler,
            # our only hope is to raise it again *while inside the handler*
            while True:
                _set_async_exc(target_id, _system_exit)

                # short randomised wait times to 'surprise' an exception
                # handler
                self._importer.join(
                    timeout=random.uniform(1e-4, 1e-5)
                )
                if not self._importer.is_alive():
                    return
        finally:
            sys.setswitchinterval(old_interval)


def import_with_timeout(modulename, import_timeout=5, exit_timeout=1):
    importer = TimeLimitedImporter(modulename, import_timeout)
    return importer.result(exit_timeout)
```

If the code can't be killed, it'll be running in a daemon thread, meaning you can at least exit Python gracefully.

Use it like this:

```
module = import_with_timeout(modulename)
```

for a default 5 second timeout, and a 1 second wait to see if the import really is unkillable.

Comment: very informative, just found another related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread